# Como fazer uma imagem dividir o texto de dentro de uma div de largura limitada?

Tags: html, css

Como fazer que uma `<img>` quebre o texto de dentro de uma `<div>` de largura limitada?

Por exemplo, com esse código:

```
<style>
    #imagem {
        float:left;
    }

    #container {
        width:250px;
        background:#ccc;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <img id="imagem" src="stack.png" width="150" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Quisque molestie justo et hendrerit molestie.
</div>
```

tenho esse resultado:
[image: resultado]
onde as palavras preenchem o espaço horizontal deixado pela `<img>`.

O que estou tentando fazer é, que uma `<img>` da mesma largura do `#container`, se ajuste no meio da 2ª e 3ª linha, fazendo o texto se dividir. Queria que esse código:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="imagem" src="stack.png" width="250" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Quisque molestie justo et hendrerit molestie.
</div>
```

produzisse esse resultado:
[image: esperado]

Queria que a imagem viesse exatamente depois da segunda linha. Esse texto vem de um campo no banco de dados, vem assim, inteiro. Queria uma alternativa que não precisasse da linguagem de programação para quebrar o texto em partes.

Comment: Separar o texto, colocando uma parte antes da img e a outra parte depois não resolve o teu problema?

Comment: @haykou Sim, mas daí teria que depender de alguma linguagem de programação, e queria uma alternativa que não dependesse de linguagem de programação.

Comment: @haykou Seria quase como um `float` vertical.

Comment: eu digo só deixar <div id="container"> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Quisque molestie justo et", depois a tag da imagem e abaixo dela o resto do texto "hendrerit molestie."

Comment: Estou pegando o texto "Lorem ipsum" do banco de dados e colocando em uma variável. Pra fazer desse jeito que falou, teria que dividir o conteúdo dessa variável em 2, pra exibir a primeira parte, então exibir a imagem e depois a segunda parte do texto dividido. Eu queria saber se há alguma alternativa em css/html para não ter que dividir o texto através da minha linguagem de programação.

Comment: entendi, coloca isso do banco na pergunta que acho que vai facilitar alguém te ajudar

Comment: Realmente com HTML e CSS putos você não vai conseguir fazer isso dessa forma. Você realmente precisa que a imagem esteja dentro da string. Porque não salvar no banco a imagem dentro da string?

Comment: Porque na hora de salvar eu teria que calcular onde quebraria a segunda linha do texto que está sendo salvo. É exatamente o problema que estou tentando evitar na hora de exibir o conteúdo.

Comment: To com o @ErlonCharles nessa. To tentando fazer aqui mas acho que com CSS puro não vai rolar.

Comment: Acredito que não há uma solução trivial que seja flexível o suficiente. O ideal seria dividir o texto previamente e definir dois parágrafos separados. Algums exemplos de soluções pra problemas parecidos podem ser encontradas: https://css-tricks.com/float-center/ http://alistapart.com/article/crosscolumn Mas note que elas endereçam layouts com a imagem entre duas colunas.

Comment: Sim, com CSS puro não rolou, acabei recorrendo à linguagem. Interessante é que a resposta do @FuadSaud é quase a solução para a questão. Talvez com alguns ajustes...

Answer (score 1):

É preciso aplicar o atributo `shape-outside: border-box;` na imagem para que o texto fique fluido em torno da imagem.

Para que exatas duas linhas fiquem definidas acima da imagem, é necessário definir o `margin-top` da imagem duas vezes o valor do `line-height` do texto.

```css
#container {
  width: 250px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#txt {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#imagem {
  float: left;
  shape-outside: border-box;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
    <span id="txt">
    <img id="imagem"
        src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/7046847_preview.png"
        width="250" />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Quisque molestie justo et hendrerit molestie.
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A minha solução seria essa para o seu problema, porem você teria que dar os espaços dentro do html, sendo assim não sei se daria certo no seu caso, isso é tipo uma "gambiarra"

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#imagem {
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
    }

    #container {
        width:250px;
        background:#ccc;
    }
p{
  white-space:pre;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque molestie justo et 
    
  
  
  

  
hendrerit molestie.</p>
    <img id="imagem" src="stack.png" width="250" />
    
</div>
```

Comment: Mas daí implica que eu sei onde a segunda linha vai quebrar, pois tenho que adicionar os espaços logo depois dela. O texto pode ser qualquer um, com qualquer variação na quantidade de caracteres. Queria que o css se encarregasse disso, como se encarrega de quebrar as palavras em uma div de largura limitada.